# degree of the complete field over a field

Tags: field-theory

Consider some field $F$ and its algebraic closure $\bar{F}$. What are the possible values of $n_F = [\bar{F}:F]$? For example, if $F=\mathbb{Q}$, then $n_F=\infty$, however $n_\mathbb{R}=2$.

I'd like to know in general what values $n$ can take, that is, I want to find the set of all naturals $k$ for which there exists a field $F$ st. $n_F=k$. I have examples for $k=1,2,\infty$ however I don't have any others and would like to know if there are any examples.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate but no other values of $k$ are possible.

Comment: If its a duplicate, do you know where the original question is? Thanks

Comment: Almost, I would like to find a proof that these are the only possible values of k, however this is not given in either the wikipedia article or the MSE question. Where might I find such a proof? Thanks

Comment: There's a proof at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I will close the question.